# "Дорожайший" — есть ли такое слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Встретил недавно в тексте слово "дорожайший". Но, насколько я знаю, есть слово "дражайший". Или первый вариант тоже допустим?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Слова дорожайший теоретически вполне может быть как превосходная степень прилагательного дорогой. И у Даля такое слово отмечается. Но в современных словарях дается только форма сравнительной степени - дороже. А слово дражайший - это форма превосходной степени к старославянскому варианту - драгой. В современном языке употребляется только в иронично-шутливом значении при обращении к супругу, например.

Comment: В словарях - не знаю, а в языке вполне себе встречается.